# If condition is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, if-statement, canvas

I got this code here:

```js
 

       var player = {
            ATK: 30
        }
        function start(place) {
         if (place == 'goldMine') {
          canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
          ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          var player = {
           x: 0,
           y: 197.5
          };
          var slope = {
           x: 159,
           y: 198.5,
           up: false
          };
          var gold = {
           x: 240,
           y: 188,
           mined: false,
                    health: 20,
           x1: 200,
           y1: 188,
           mined1: false
          };
          ctx.font = '15px Monospace';
          var move = setInterval(function(){player.x += 7;},50)
          var draw = setInterval(function() {
           ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
           ctx.fillText('\\o/',player.x,player.y);
           ctx.fillText("__________________",0,195.5);
           ctx.fillText("/",slope.x,slope.y);
           ctx.fillText("______________________________________________________",165.5,184.5);
           ctx.fillText("/0\\",gold.x,gold.y);
           ctx.fillText("/0\\",gold.x1,gold.y1);
           if (player.x >= slope.x - 23 && !slope.up) {
            player.y -= 10;
            slope.up = true;
           }
         
           if (player.x >= gold.x - 23 && gold.mined == false) {
            clearInterval(move)
console.log(gold.health)
                        dam = setInterval(function(){gold.health -= player.ATK}, 1000)
console.log(gold.health)
           }
           if (gold.health <= 0) {
             gold.mined = true; gold.y = 210; move = setInterval(function(){player.x += 7;},50)
           } 
           if (player.x >= gold.x1 - 23.99 && gold.mined == false) {
            gold.y1 = 250;
            gold.mined1 = true;
           }
          }, 50)
         }
        }
        start('goldMine')
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width='985' height='200'></canvas>
```

When the `gold.health` is subtract by `player.ATK`, it returns 20 then undefined. What I expected is it should subtract `gold.health` by `player.ATK` every 1000ms. But why do it returns undefined? Can i solve this using just javascript?

Comment: can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you are using timers the wrong way, basicly dont use setInterval. Look up `requestAnmationFrame` (rAF) and study the examples.

You code problem

Javascript is blocking, that means when some code is running, no other javascript on the same page (Javascript context) can run, this includes events. Timers are events and thus will not fire while you are inside a function.

You have something like this

```
var myval;
function doSomething(){
    myval = 10
    console.log(myVal); // outputs 10
    setInterval(function(){
          myval -= 1;
    },1);
    console.log(myVal); // outputs 10 because the interval function
                        // will never fire between to two console calls.

    // even if I keep the code running for 2 seconds
    var waitTill = performance.now() + 2000;
    while(performance.now() < waitTill);  // wait two seconds 
                                          // BTW don't ever do this.
    // two second and the interval function still has not fired.
    console.log(myVal); // still outputs 10
    // more code
    ... blah blah
    // and exit
}
// only when the code has exited can the timer function fire
// If the interval is short you and you had the 2 second wait
// you would get many interval firing one after the other (or the browser crashes)
```

With games you try to use only one event timer. The rAF fires an event once every 1/60th second (if no Javascript code is blocking it that is)

```
function mainLoop(time){ // the time is set by rAF
    // inside this function do all you need to do with your game

    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

If you want something to happen at a regular interval do it in the rAF function by tracking the time.

```
var nextDamage = -1;   
function mainLoop(time){ 
    if(startDamage){ // this starts the regular event
          nextDamage = time + 1000;
          startDamage = false; // clear the flag so you dont keep resetting the time.

    // Every time this loop function is run check
    // if time is greater than nextDamage 
    }else if(nextDamage !== -1 && time >= nextDamage){
         // do the damage
         damage -= 10;
         nextDamage += 2000; // set the next damage time.
    }


    To stop the damage happening just do
    if(stopDamage){
         nextDamage = -1;
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

Comment: How do I stop the player from moving?

Comment: I fixed my code, and weird enought, it still returning NaN.